# Excel VBA Userform Exit

Tags: excel, vba

I have this userform in Excel. Every time I close/exit the userform, the workbook also closes. Is this normal? I'm very new with excel VBA or with the whole coding thing actually. How can I prevent/stop this from happening? What I want to happen is when I close the userform, a certain sheet in the workbook will be displayed.

Here's my code

```
Private Sub ExitForm_Click()
Sheets("Face").Activate
Unload PayrollSystem
End Sub

'To disable X button
 Private Sub UserForm_QueryClose(Cancel As Integer, CloseMode As Integer)
 If CloseMode = 0 Then
    Cancel = True
    MsgBox "The X-button is disabled, there's an EXIT button on the form.", vbCritical
  End If

  End Sub

'To Add Minimize Button
Private Declare Function FindWindowA Lib "USER32" _
(ByVal lpClassName As String, _
ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Long

Private Declare Function GetWindowLongA Lib "USER32" _
(ByVal hWnd As Long, _
ByVal nIndex As Long) As Long

Private Declare Function SetWindowLongA Lib "USER32" _
(ByVal hWnd As Long, _
ByVal nIndex As Long, _
ByVal dwNewLong As Long) As Long

Option Explicit

Sub FormatUserForm(UserFormCaption As String)
Dim hWnd            As Long
Dim exLong          As Long
hWnd = FindWindowA(vbNullString, UserFormCaption)
exLong = GetWindowLongA(hWnd, -16)
If (exLong And &H20000) = 0 Then
    SetWindowLongA hWnd, -16, exLong Or &H20000
Else
End If
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

Call FormatUserForm(Me.Caption)

End Sub
```

Comment: It would help if you showed us your code.

Comment: Hi, I've edited the question to include my code. Thanks.

Comment: That can't be all the code. Closing a userform doesn't close a workbook unless you coded it to.

Comment: well, i also have one that disables the X button in the userform and another for adding a minimize button to the userform.

Comment: And is there any code involved that shows the form? Are there any statement after the show-Command? Have you debugged your code?

Comment: Oh. Got it. It was on the macro that shows the userform. Thank you very much.